# Grails : call to public action redirects to login page

Tags: javascript, grails

I am making cross domain ajax call from php to grails application .

My php script:

```
$uid=$_GET['uid'];
function getData($uid)

{
    $dataUrl='http://localhost:8080/profile/user/teacher?id='.$uid;
    $json=file_get_contents($dataUrl);
    print_r($json);

}
getData($uid);
```

Javascript which calls this php script is

```
$.getJSON('userdata.php?uid'+1,function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

here when i do getJSON call it goes to login page of my application , even though i have not checking for logged in that particular method. i.e its a public method which i can access without login.

i am using springsecurity plugin for authentication management.

Comment: so, you get redirected to login page when you're requesting your PHP script, not a Grails app, right?

Comment: And what happpens if you access in the browser `http://localhost:8080/profile/user/teacher?id=1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because of spring security(may be your action or controller have security annotation or may be action is secure via url mapping in config).

You can bypassed

*if using annotation*

```
@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
def teacher() {
    ....
}
```

*if using url mapping in config*

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
...
'/user/teacher/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
...
]
```